# Get range between FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE

Tags: sql, sqlite, range, window-functions, analytical

| timestamp | id | scope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-23 12:52:34.159999 UTC | 1 | enter_page |
| 2021-01-23 12:53:02.342 UTC | 1 | view_product |
| 2021-01-23 12:53:02.675 UTC | 1 | checkout |
| 2021-01-23 12:53:04.342 UTC | 1 | search_page |
| 2021-01-23 12:53:24.513 UTC | 1 | checkout |

I am trying to get all the values between the FIRST_VALUE and LAST VALUE in the column 'scope' using WINDOWS/ANALYTICAL Functions

I already get the first_value() = **enter_page**
and the last_value() == **checkout**

by using windows functions in SQLite

```
FIRST_VALUE(scope) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY julianday(timestamp) ASC) first_page
FIRST_VALUE(scope) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY julianday(timestamp) DESC ) last_page
```

I am trying to capture all steps in between [excluding edges]: **view_product, apartment_view, checkout[, N-field]** to later add them into a string ( unique values -STR_AGGR() )

Once done that, i will later process trying to find if the customer at somepoint during the purchase_journey open the checkout multiple times

my result should like like

| id | first_page | last_page | inbetween_pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | enter_page | checkout | view_product, checkout, search_page |

p.s. I am trying to avoid using python to process this. I would like a 'clean' way of doing this with SQL-pure

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking:

```
select id, group_concat(scope, ',')
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
      order by id, timestamp
     ) t
where 1 not in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
group by id;
```

In SQLite, `group_concat()` doesn't accept an `order by` argument.  My understanding is that it respects the ordering from the subquery, which is why the subquery has an `order by`.

Comment: That is a pretty interesting way of solving this Gordon. thanks :)  I am sure I will be able to apply this to other queries as well..    just a small detail, i think u missed the DESC part on the seqnum_desc part.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function which supports the `ORDER BY` clause so you will have the `scope`s in `inbetween_pages` in the correct order, instead of `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function which does not support the `ORDER BY` clause and the results that it returns are not guaranteed to be in a specific order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, first_page, last_page,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN timestamp NOT IN (min_timestamp, max_timestamp) THEN scope END) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) inbetween_pages
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         FIRST_VALUE(scope) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) first_page,
         FIRST_VALUE(scope) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) last_page,
         MIN(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id) min_timestamp,
         MAX(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id) max_timestamp
  FROM tablename       
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4c8c2ea65d9961eaa55be3b084ff4d01).
Results:

| id | first_page | last_page | inbetween_pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | enter_page | checkout | view_product,checkout,search_page |

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to solve this. but with a small tweak due to i need only distinct values. I did not use the window_functionality but the aggregation.

Comment: @OscarCopado if you used aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT() in your code, as I mention in my answer, you should know that its results are not guaranteed to be in a specific order.

Comment: I am aware of that  (after running your fiddle example) . In this case I just need to know if at some x-point in time this 'event' happened. thanks a lot.